# Truncate text in Ms. Excel cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working with Ms. Excel. I have a cell contains a person name. Eg :

```
Name
-------------------
Barack Hussein Obama
```

Is there any formulas to truncate the text in the cell so that it gives result as follows :

```
First Name            Middle Name             Last Name
------------------------------------------------------------------
Barrack               Hussein                 Obama
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data *always* has

1. Three names
2. No leading or trailing spaces
3. One and only one space between names

then you can use these formulas  (Full name in col `A`)

```
First Name (col B)  
=LEFT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)-1)   

Middle Name (col C)
=MID(A2,LEN(B2)+2,LEN(A2)-LEN(B2)-LEN(D2)-2) 

Last Name (col D)
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(" ",A2,LEN(B2)+2))
```

Comment: actually there are also names without the middle name, but i can handle it. at least i already know how to truncate it. thx so much for this dude !

Answer (score 0):

1. Highlight the name (or column of multiple names),
2. From the menu `Data ..... Text to Columns`.
3. Select `Delimited` and click `Next`.  Check the `Space` option.
4. Click `Next` and `Finish`.

Comment: -1 the question specifically asks for *formulas*

Comment: +1 as clearly the OP may not have been aware that a superior non-VBA approach (which this is) is possible.